# Electron capture and overlapping wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hydrogen

I'm sorry if the following question sounds a little homework-ish, but I need help understanding how to even proceed with the following problem.

In a hydrogenic atom of atomic number $Z$, the probability amplitude that the nucleus will capture an electron from its own $K$-shell is proportional to the overlap between the nuclear wavefunction :

$$\psi_n(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi r_N^3}}e^{\frac{r}{r_N}}$$

And the electron wave function :

$$\psi_e(\vec{r})=\frac{Z^{3/2}}{\sqrt{8\pi a_0^3}}e^{-\frac{Zr}{a_0}}$$

Here $a_0$ is the Bohr radius and $r_N$ is the nuclear radius, which varies as $r_N\propto Z^{0.37}$. The probability of electron capture, to a very good approximation will be proportional to $Z^\alpha$. Find $\alpha$.

I've no idea how to even proceed with this kind of problems involving overlap of wavefunctions, and probability. If anyone can even guide me as to how I can even proceed with this problem, that would be really helpful.